# How I create Octagon shape in google map?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I would like to draw a Octagonal shape.[image]

I don't know how to achieve this. Here is my code -

func drawOctagonalShape(){

```
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.4, longitude:-122.0, zoom: 10)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true;
    self.view = mapView
   
    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0)
    marker.title = "India"
    //marker.snippet = "Malaysia"
    marker.map = mapView
    let rect = GMSMutablePath()
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.0))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.2))
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.2))
    
    // Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
    let polygon = GMSPolygon(path: rect)
    polygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05);
    polygon.strokeColor = UIColor.init(hue: 210, saturation: 88, brightness: 84, alpha: 1)
    //polygon.strokeColor = .black
    polygon.strokeWidth = 2
    polygon.map = mapView
}
```

Comment: That's an octagon

Answer (score 0):

Octagon is basically 8 points distributed equally on a circle. You can create a method like the following:

```
func generateCircle(around center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, pointCount: Int = 8, rotation: Double = 0) -> [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
    (0..<count).map { index in
        let angle = rotation + (Double(index)/Double(pointCount))*Double.pi*2.0
        return .init(latitude: center.latitude + cos(angle)*radius, longitude: center.longitude + sin(angle)*radius)
    }
}
```

I hope the code speaks for itself. You would use it in your code like

```
let rect = GMSMutablePath()
generateCircle(around center: myCenter, radius: someSmallRadius, pointCount: 8, rotation: 0).forEach { coordinate in
    rect.add(coordinate)
}
```

I would expect this to work in most cases. There are 2 potential problems however:

1. I am unsure how this would behave around edges of both longitude and latitude.
2. Radius expressed in degrees may be a bit incorrect at some points

Would it not be easier to simply generate an image and place that on your map?